# Landing page occupying the entire height of the monitor - for every resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, resolution, frontend

I want to get the effect like on this website: http://make-lemonade.co/themes/kodax/
Landing page occupying the entire height of the monitor

To do this the page I use Bootstrap 3.1.1.

My code:

HTML:

```
    <div id="panorama-home">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                </ul>
                <h3 class="text-muted">
                    <img src="img/LOGO1.png" />
                </h3>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-md-12">
                    <h1 style="font-size:52px; padding-top:140px; text-align:center">
                        Text field
                    </h1>
                    <!--<p style="margin-left:160px; color:white;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>-->
                </div>
            </div>

        <div id="boxlinks" class="arrow" style="position: relative; text-align:center; padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:30px;">
            <a href="#marketing-text"><img src="img/down-arrow.png" style="width:100px; height:100px;"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#panorama-home {
    background: url("img/home.jpg") no-repeat center center; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding:120px 0;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @Ruddy what is unclear?

Comment: Everything you said in your question.

Comment: Makes more sense but you will get no help here. Your asking people to write the code for you. You should go search around as there are lots of tutorials that can help you create this.

Answer (score 0):

set height as 100vh

```
#panorama-home {
    ...
    height: 100vh;
}
```